# Yocto Jethro: Is root login completely disabled when I remove "debug-tweaks"

Tags: root, yocto, openembedded

I removed "debug-tweaks" from EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES in my local.conf.
Does this completely disable root logins? Or just that root password has defaulted to some other password?

I do not see anything set to EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES

```
$ bitbake -e | grep "^EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES=""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-features-image

If you don't enable debug-tweaks (or more specifically, empty-root-password) then it is up to you to set the root password.  If you didn't set it then the root user has no password, so they can't login.

To set users and passwords you can use the extrausers class:

http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-extrausers

Comment: does it mean the password for root is locked? Like is for the Ubuntu machines? I am trying to achieve an effect like the Ubuntu. **Where, locking the password of the named account, disables password by changing it to a value which matches no possible encrypted value. Users with a locked password are not allowed to change their password.**

Comment: Sort of: there is no password set, so you can't login.  Very different to the password being set to <empty string>.